# Why is this SQL UPDATE QUERY returning false?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I'm making a game and I ran into some trouble with a query that won't seem to work what ever I try to do. I have four variables (that are validated)

```
$id, $plantId, $stage, $started
```

And my query looks like this...

```
$sql = "
        UPDATE growth
        SET plantId = '$plantId', stage = '$stage', started = '$started'
        WHERE id = '$id'
";
```

It returns false, but I tried the same query in phpMyAdmin and it worked!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to give us more than that. What API are using? Have you tried checking the value of `$sql`? Where is the code where you run it?

Comment: What's the actual runtime value of the query being executed?  What is the actual error from the database?

Comment: What __exactly__ returns `false`?

Comment: Just before your execute code do `echo $sql` and edit your question with the result.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt
I was able to figure out that I somehow got a pair of extra ' ' that didn't belong there.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use plain MySql. I know that learning new technologies might feel overwhelming but we live in year 2016. There are plenty of tools that will make your life easier.

For example DiBi database layer:
https://github.com/dg/dibi

You can use either **OFFICIAL VERSION** as shown in the documentation:

SELECT:

```
dibi::query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', $id);
```

INSERT

```
$arr = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'is_admin'  => TRUE,
];
dibi::query('INSERT INTO users', $arr);
```

UPDATE

```
dibi::query('UPDATE users SET', $arr, 'WHERE `id`=?', $x);
```

Or you can use **FLUENT VERSION**:

SELECT

```
$res = dibi::select('product_id')->as('id')
    ->select('title')
    ->from('products')
    ->innerJoin('orders')->using('(product_id)')
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->fetchAll();
```

INSERT

```
$record = array(
    'title'  => 'Výrobek',
    'price'  => 318,
    'active' => TRUE,
);
dibi::insert('products', $record)
    ->execute();
```

UPDATE

```
$record = array(
    'title'  => 'Výrobek',
    'price'  => 318,
    'active' => TRUE,
);
dibi::update('products', $record)
    ->where('product_id = %d', $id);
    ->execute();
```

It will make your life much easier. Learning fluent version and concatenating your queries is even quite fun. When you need to test your query just use test() method.

You do not even have to worry about sql injections.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll look in to that once I've got the basics down. But I find when trying to learn something it helps to understand the raw core first. Then its much easier to learn all kinds of packs built around it.